# Control legend colors in tactile::bwplot2

Tags: lattice, bwplot

In this reproducible example below with the tactile package, the colors are automatically chosen for the boxplots and corresponding legend. However, I would like to customize the colors of the boxplots and legend.

```
tactile::bwplot2(runif(1000) ~ cut(runif(1000), c(0,0.3,0.6,1)) | as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
             groups = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE), auto.key = TRUE)
```

[image: boxplots with default colors]

However, when I tried to do this, the colors in the boxplots changed but the legend colors did not:

Here I create a new color scheme:

```
coolNewPars <- list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 21, cex = 2, col = "gray20",
                           fill = continentColors$color))
```

And then plot the boxplots again, with auto.key instructed to place the legend contents into 2 columns and the par.settings set to coolNewPars:

```
tactile::bwplot2(runif(1000) ~ cut(runif(1000), c(0,0.3,0.6,1)) | as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
             groups = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE), auto.key = list(columns = 2),par.settings = coolNewPars)
```

[image: boxplots with coolNewPars colors]

How do I force the legend colors to match the coolNewPars colors?

Comment: Code for getting the Continent Colors: gdURL <- "http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/notOcto/STAT545A/examples/gapminder/data/gapminderContinentColors.txt"
(continentColors <- read.delim(file = gdURL, as.is = 3)) # protect color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lattice::panel.superpose()` uses `trellis.get.par("superpose.symbol")` to differentiate between groups, whilst
the function that draws the key uses `"superpose.polygon"`, or something like it.

In any case, here is a solution (although it is awkward):

```
coolNewPars <- list(superpose.polygon = list(col = 2:3),
                    superpose.symbol = list(fill = 2:3))

tactile::bwplot2(runif(1000) ~ cut(runif(1000), c(0,0.3,0.6,1)) | as.factor(c(1,2,3)), 
                 groups = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                 auto.key = TRUE,
                 par.settings = coolNewPars)
```

[image]